# how to quit a blocking read thread when timeout happen?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

Here I create a thread to read data from uart in linux, but sometimes, there is no data from uart, so that thread is blocking for a very long time. The question is how to set a timeout branch to let thread quit when TIMEOUT happens. demo code is as following,

```
void* recvthread(void *para){

    unsigned char buf[128]={0};
    int ret = -1;
    devpara_t *localpara = (devpara_t *)para;

    for(;;){
        ret = read(localpara->fd ,buf, 128);
        if(ret < 0)
        {
           printf("error!\n");
        }
    }
}

int main(){

    int ret = 0;
    devpara_t *dpara = malloc(sizeof(devpara_t));
    
    dpara->hd = openuart("/ttyS0");  //uart port
    if(dpara->hd < 0)
        return -1;
    configuart(dpara->hd,115200,8,1,NOPAR,1/*stopbits*/);
        
    ret = pthread_create(&wtid, NULL , recvthread, (void *)dpara);

    if (ret < 0) {
        perror ("pthread_create failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    pthread_join(rtid,NULL);

    if(dpara)
      free();
    
    return ret;
}
```

Data arrive at uart in random way, sometimes within 1s, sometimes more than 2~3s.

Comment: Don't use `read()` directly, first use `poll()` or `select()` with a timeout and only call `read()` when data is available to be read.

Comment: See stty min 0 and time 1 setting to tell serial driver how to timeout on read.

Comment: What is `devpara_t` and why do you allocate it on the heap? Is it extremely large? Please provide a [mre]. Sidenote:  Checking if `malloc` succeded at the end of the program is too late. You've already used `dpara` so if `malloc` failed, your program will have already gone bonkers by the time it reaches `if(dpara)` ... Oh, and `free()` needs an argument. Must likely `dpara`.